# Session variable is null in SiteMapResolve

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, session-variables

I'm using the default Web.Sitemap and SiteMapPath on my master page. What I want to do is when a certain node is displayed (whether as current or a parent node) the title is changed to a session variable value (if it exists).

For example, this:

```
Home / Search / Breed Information / Individual Information
```

would become

```
Home / Search / Chihuahua / Individual Information
```

I added the SiteMapResolve event handler as per Microsoft's advice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178425(v=vs.100).aspx

However, every time I ask for the session value, it resolves to a null value.

I set the session value by using

```
Session["BreedID"] = breedID
```

which is an integer value.

```
SiteMapNode SiteMap_SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
    SiteMapNode tempNode = currentNode;
    var breedInformationNode = GetNodeByTitle("Breed Information", tempNode);
    if (breedInformationNode != null)
    {
        if (e.Context.Request["BreedName"] != null)
        {
            breedInformationNode.Title = e.Context.Request["BreedName"].ToString().Replace("-", " ");
        }
        else if (e.Context.Session["BreedName"] != null) // This is always null
        {
            breedInformationNode.Title = e.Context.Session["BreedName"].ToString().Replace("-", " ");
        }
    }
    return currentNode;
}

SiteMapNode GetNodeByTitle(string nodeName, SiteMapNode node)
{
    if (node.Title == nodeName)
    {
        return node;
    }
    SiteMapNode retNode = null;
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (SiteMapNode item in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            retNode = GetNodeByTitle(nodeName, item);
            if (retNode != null)
            {
                return retNode;
            }
        }
    }
    return retNode;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `Session["BreedID"] = breedID`? Are you sure that code is getting executed?

Comment: In the child page, I have several references to 'Session["BreedID"]' that are not evaluated as null (the same page load). It's just in the master page that this happens.
I'm afraid of this being an idiosyncrasy of .NET that only applies to this one program in this one situation.

Comment: Is it possible you have separate web.config files for different directories that might have settings related to Session?